# Failed to connect to localhost port 8090: Connection refused

Tags: java, localhost

I SSH into a remote Ubuntu virtual machine and tried to load some data using the following command:

```
$ curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @quickstart/wikiticker-index.json localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8090: Connection refused
```

What should I do to connect?

The following is what I'm running in that directory:

```sh
java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/historical/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/historical:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server historical
java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/broker/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/broker:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server broker
java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/coordinator/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/coordinator:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server coordinator
java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/overlord/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/overlord:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server overlord
java `cat conf-quickstart/druid/middleManager/jvm.config | xargs` -cp "conf-quickstart/druid/_common:conf-quickstart/druid/middleManager:lib/*" io.druid.cli.Main server middleManager
```

After running each `java...` line above, it began repeating the following:

```
2017-04-28T23:51:13,769 INFO [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2017-04-28T23:51:13,769 WARN [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at 
sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9-1757313]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1141) [zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:3.4.9-1757313]
```

Comment: This supposes that there should be a process listening on port 8090. Apparently, there isn't. However, with the information that you give us, we can't tell what process that could be, and why it isn't there.

Comment: @jos Please see my additional comment. What other information could I provide?

Comment: First, check if there is a server listening to port 8090: `sudo netstat -pnlt | grep ':8090'`. If not, the druid server is not running properly and you should consult the druid log files to find out why not.

Comment: Run your `curl` command and then immediately `echo $?`. If the output is 7, then you have the following error: `7      Failed to connect to host.`, what probably means there is no host listening to this port. Check out whether you are correctly starting your java server program.

Comment: @jos That didn't give anything back. I tried `netstat -l`. I've added the result in the question.

Comment: No, as @thiagowfx notices, you should check out why the server program hasn't run properly.

Comment: @thiagowfx The output is 7. Please see the immediate output of running each of those java commands (added in the question). Is that where the problem is? Or does it have to do with the installed druid directory? (I'm assuming there's no problem with my openjdk).

Comment: @jos Please see my comment to thiagowfx.

Comment: Yes. This is the problem. You have an exception in your "main" function, therefore the server isn't even being launched. It looks like you are missing at least one class in your jdk installation. Does the druid program have any requirements or dependencies? Make sure you have them installed.

Comment: @thiagowfx I've resolved the missing packages issue. It began repeating the following:  `...INFO [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)...WARN [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: @jos Please see my latest edit.